# Producing an error if a command is not given enough arguments

Tags: macros, error-writing

I have a bunch of `\newcommand` macros that each take several arguments. Sometimes I forget one of the arguments, and this can lead to the output not being as expected, as in this MWE, where the `\foo` command thinks its fourth argument is a newline character:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\foo}[4]{%
    The four arguments were #1, #2, #3 and #4.%
}
\begin{document}

Here is the output of my command: \foo{one}{two}{three}

\end{document}
```

In a more complex situation forgetting an argument can lead to very uninformative error messages whose cause is hard to track down.

Because of this, I would like to make the curly braces around the arguments compulsory. In other words, I would like to redefine the command `\foo` such that the above example will fail to compile, with an error message along the lines of "Command `\foo` requires four arguments." Is this possible?

Comment: do you just want to catch end of paragraph (use `\newcommand*` instead of `\newcommand`) or do you want an error from  `\foo 1 2 3 4` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'd like an error from `\foo 1 2 3 4` also. The syntax doesn't have to be `\foo{1}{2}{3}{4}`, it could be something like `\foo{1,2,3,4}` instead - the point is just to make sure there's no way I can think I supplied the right number of arguments when I didn't.

Comment: Ulrich's answer then:-) Be careful what you ask for though.

Comment: `\foo{1,2,3,4}` completely changes the question: it's easy to check for that even in expandable commands, eg `\cline{1-2}` {which is two arguments separated by `-` but same idea)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry for changing the question so much with that comment - I didn't realise that would be the case.

Answer (score 5):

In comments you suggested other input syntax would be acceptable

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{\xfoo#1,\MISSING,\MISSING,\MISSING,\MISSING,\xfoo}
\def\xfoo#1,#2,#3,#4,#5\xfoo{%
    The four arguments were #1, #2, #3 and #4.%
}
\begin{document}

Here is the output of my command: \foo{one,two,three}

\end{document}
```

gives

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \MISSING 
                    
l.8 ...e output of my command: \foo{one,two,three}
                                                  
?
```

You could obviously define `\MISSING` to give a more specific error if needed.

Answer (score 3):

A routine for grabbing curly-brace-nested arguments requires detecting curly braces by "looking ahead" at the next token in the token-stream. You can use `\futurelet` for obtaining information about the *meaning* of the next token, but by examining the meaning you cannot distinguish an explicit `{1`-character-token from an implicit character token like `\bgroup` (defined as `\let\bgroup={`). Besides this approaches via `\futurelet` do not work out in expansion-contexts as `\futurelet` denotes an assignment which - if at all - is carried out some time after expansion took place.

If expandability is not an issue and if you really desire such an interface, instead of implementing things based on `\futurelet` yourself, you can try with xparse's **deprecated** `g`- or `G`-type-argument. But you might be interested in the remarks with the GitHub-issue "[xparse documentation deprecated options inside main text #1069](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1069#issuecomment-1069714768)".

Besides this, with `g`- and `G`-type-arguments the lookahead for detecting the presence of a curly opening brace seems to be based on examining the meaning of the next token of the token-stream and thus can be fooled by `\bgroup`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Use expl3-infrastructure for providing error-message in case there are not
% enough curly-brace-nested arguments:
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_type_prop { MyStuff } {}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_name_prop { MyStuff } {Macro-Defined-In-Preamble:}
\msg_new:nnnn {MyStuff} 
              {Not enough arguments}
              {Macro~#1:~Command~#1~requires~#2~arguments,~you~provided~#3.}
              {When~specifying~arguments~make~sure~they~are~nested~between~curly~braces.}
\cs_new:Npn \NotEnoughArgsError #1#2#3 {
  \exp_args:Nne \use:nn {
    \msg_error:nnnnn {MyStuff} {Not enough arguments}
   }{{\iow_char:N \\ \cs_to_str:N#1}}{#2}{#3}
}%
\cs_new:Npn \ttdetokenize #1 {\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand\foo{gggg}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\NotEnoughArgsError{\foo}{4}{0}}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\NotEnoughArgsError{\foo}{4}{1}}{%
      \IfNoValueTF{#3}{\NotEnoughArgsError{\foo}{4}{2}}{%
       \IfNoValueTF{#4}{\NotEnoughArgsError{\foo}{4}{3}}{%
          The four arguments were \ttdetokenize{#1}, 
          \ttdetokenize{#2}, \ttdetokenize{#3} and \ttdetokenize{#4}.%
       }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|p{.4\textwidth}|}
\hline
\textbf{Input}&\textbf{Result}\\
\hline
\verb*|\foo {A} {B} {C} {D}|&\foo {A} {B} {C} {D}\\
\hline
%
% Error-message about providing only 3 arguments:
\verb*|\foo {A} {B} {C}D|&\foo {A} {B} {C}D\\
\hline
%
% Error-message about providing only 2 arguments:
\verb*|\foo {A} {B} CD|&\foo {A} {B} CD\\
\hline
%
% Error-message about providing only 1 argument:
\verb*|\foo {A} BCD|&\foo {A} BCD\\
\hline
%
% Error-message about providing 0 arguments:
\verb*|\foo ABCD|&\foo ABCD\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Be aware of this one:}}\\
\hline
% !!! No error message at all!!!
\verb*|\foo \bgroup {B} {C} {D}|&\foo \bgroup {B} {C} {D}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Excerpt of console-output:

```
! Macro-Defined-In-Preamble: Error: Macro \foo: Command \foo requires 4
(Macro-Defined-In-Preamble:)        arguments, you provided 3.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.44 \verb*|\foo {A} {B} {C}D|&\foo {A} {B} {C}D
                                                \\
? 

! Macro-Defined-In-Preamble: Error: Macro \foo: Command \foo requires 4
(Macro-Defined-In-Preamble:)        arguments, you provided 2.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.48 \verb*|\foo {A} {B} CD|&\foo {A} {B} C
                                           D\\
? 

! Macro-Defined-In-Preamble: Error: Macro \foo: Command \foo requires 4
(Macro-Defined-In-Preamble:)        arguments, you provided 1.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.52 \verb*|\foo {A} BCD|&\foo {A} B
                                    CD\\
? 

! Macro-Defined-In-Preamble: Error: Macro \foo: Command \foo requires 4
(Macro-Defined-In-Preamble:)        arguments, you provided 0.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.56 \verb*|\foo ABCD|&\foo A
                             BCD\\
?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\NewDocumentCommand` macro to create commands (now it's native, in old document you might need to load `xparse`). It takes as input the name of the macro, a string describing the arguments (`m` is a mandatory argument, `O{xxx}` is an optional argument whose default value is `xxx`…) and the macro definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mmmm}{%
    The four arguments were #1, #2, #3 and #4.%
}
\begin{document}

Here is the output of my command: \foo{one}{two}{three}

\end{document}
```

```
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \foo  was complete.
```

Comment: This is only because the argument is not long and the missing argument results to be a (implicit) `\par`; you can achieve the same as the OP error changing the last argument to `m+` (or `+m`, I forgot.). Try `\foo{a}{b}{c} surprise`... 

Comment: But this does point to another fix for OP's MWE: using `\newcommand*{\foo}[4]{...}` would have resulted in the same runaway argument error.

Comment: `\foo1234` would give no error with this definition

Comment: Oh good point, I didn't noticed that. I'll let the answer in case some people might be interested by this simple solution.